# How can I pass the result of `qrcode.make` to Flask's `send_file`, without saving the file to disk first?

Tags: python, api, file, flask

currently I'm using "send_file" from flask, but it makes a read on the path to open the file. I already have loaded the file and want to return it, though I can't find a function for that. Any Ideas?

Example:

```
return send_file(filename_or_fp="../file.jpg", mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

I want to return it like that:

```
file = qrcode.make("sample text")
return send_file(filename_or_fp=file, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

send_files returns following error: `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Please show the code where you 'load' the file.

Comment: Updated question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save `file` to a `BytesIO` buffer, then pass that to the `send_file` function.

Also, you don't need to write `filename_or_fp=` as that is a positional argument.

The app should look like:

```
import qrcode
from flask import Flask, send_file
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    file = qrcode.make('sample text')
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    file.save(buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    return send_file(buf, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```